# i am getting the error "Passowrd is wrong" when tried to login , i used pre save validation in mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, mern, bcrypt

before implementing the pre save hook in mongoose the login api is working perfectly but after implementing the pre save hook i consistently getting the password is wrong error i tire to log the password hashed when register and user.password when login the both are same but compare password is throw false again . i tried many times to solve the issue but failed

i am trying to add one more security layer for password hashing using mongoose pre save hook and stuck in a situation where i need help of professionals to get me out

my logi api(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipcoW.png)

```
     export const userLogin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log("Received Email:", email);
    console.log("Received Password:", password);
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    console.log("Stored Hashed Password:", user.password);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(200).send({
        message: "Email is not registered",
        success: false,
      });
    }
    const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    console.log("Password Comparison Result:", checkPassword);

    if (!checkPassword) {
      return res.status(200).send({
        message: "Password is wrong",
        success: false,
      });
    } else {
      let token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      });
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Login Succes",
        success: true,
        data: token,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: "Internal Server Error",
      success: false,
    });
  }
};`

my mongoose model pre save hook(https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1f6x.png)`import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      match: /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/,
    },
    dob: {
      type: Date,
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    newPassword: {
      type: String,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "user",
    },
    otpCode: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Verify Password Method
userSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

// Get Password Hash Method
userSchema.methods.getPasswordHash = async function (password) {
  const rounds = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, rounds);
  return hash;
};

// Pre-save Hook
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  console.log("pre hook: validate username");
  try {
    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    const isUsernameValid = regex.test(this.userName);
    if (!isUsernameValid) {
      console.log("this will stop execution of next middlewares");
      throw new Error("username is not alphanumeric");
    }
    if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();
    const trimmedPassword = this.password.trim();
    const rounds = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, rounds);
    this.password = hash;
    console.log("database hashed password", this.password);

    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
});
const userModal = new mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
export default userModal;
```

Comment: You do know that  when you do `const trimmedPassword = this.password.trim();` that `this.password` isn't trimmed right, because you never use `trimmedPassword` anywhere...

Comment: thanks for your support, the error is solved

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you got it working.